# PCmanFM desktop crash

Tags: pcmanfm

Hi there I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and PCmanFM as the replacement for UNITY desktop. 
I am wondering how I might go about re-launcing PCmanFM desktop environment after it has crashed. What happens is that it crashes and unity takes over the desktop.

To relaunch I have tried (without success):

- typing pcmanfm in terminal
- logging out and back in again.

  The only method I have found to work is to reboot the machine which is not a very good solution.

Comment: PCManFM is not a desktop Environment.  Did you install the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment (LXDE) which essentially turns Ubuntu into Lubuntu or did you just install PCManFM (which is just a file manager)?

Comment: I think I must have installed the X11 as it certainly seems like an environment of some sort as it it crashes and all the icons change on desktop and the screen saver changes.  When my machine boots it actually says Edubuntu, even though I dont remember installing anything other than 12.04.

Comment: If your machine says Edubuntu when you boot, then that is your Operationg System.  It is an educational version of Ubuntu.  I do not believe that it comes with PCManFM.

Comment: I wonder how that was installed? I never downloaded it. In any case, the crash still happens and I am still wondering about a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open Synaptic Package Manager.  Search for pcmanfm.  After finding it, mark it for complete removal.  Apply the change and wait for it to be removed.  Your File Manager should be Nautilus which I believe is the default file manager.  If you want Lubuntu, your best bet is to download the newest LTS version which is 14.04.  Back up all of your data to an external source (hard drive or USB thumb drive).  Make a bootable CD or thumb drive and use it to boot your computer.  Install it on your computer.  If there are things that you do not understand you should ask.  For instance after you download the ISO you need to check the hash (MD5Sum) of the download.  Why do you need to get the new version?  Because Lubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, and 13.10 have all reached their End Of Life and are no longer supported.  Ubuntu 12.04 and Edbuntu 12.04 which you apparently have installed are supported until sometime in April 2017.  Your choice, (1) you can keep what you got after un-installing PCManFM (2) you can download and install Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I wish to keep PCmanFM as my file browser though. I also want to stay with Ubuntu 12.04/ I was simply asking how to relaunch the application after it crashes.

Comment: If that is the case simply reinstall PCManFM after you have uninstalled in.  Something wasn't installed correctly.